# If $x^2 \equiv 10 \pmod {26}$ then determine $\gcd(x,26)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was trying to solve the following exercice:

> If $x^2 \equiv 10 \pmod {26}$ then determine $\gcd(x,26)$

What I did was the following:

If $x^2 \equiv 10 \pmod {26}$ then $x^2$ has to be even, this means that:

$$2\cdot \frac{x^2}{2} \equiv 2 \cdot 5 \pmod{26} \iff \frac{x^2}{2} \equiv 5 \pmod {13} \iff x^2 \equiv 10 \pmod {13}$$

So now we know that $x^2 = 10 + k \cdot 13$. I started trying different values for $k$ and found out that if $k=2$ then $10 + k \cdot 13 = 36 = 6^2$, so $x = 6$ and $\gcd(x,26) = 2$.

The thing is: By doing this I'm only evaluating $\gcd(x,26)$ for $x = 6$, and perhaps this isn't the only value of $x$ that satisfies $x^2 \equiv 10 \pmod {26}$. How can I solve this more rigorously without having to "guess" those values of $k$ and get all solutions?

---

Edit: After reading the comments I did the following:

$\gcd(x^2 , 26) = \gcd(10,26) = 2$.

Let's then look at the prime decomposition for $x^2$. We know that has to be equal to $x^2 = 2^{2k} \cdot 13^0 \cdot y$, for some $y$ such that $2,13 \not | y$ and for $k > 0$. This means that $x = 2^k \cdot 13^0 \cdot y'$ and thus $\gcd(x,26) = 2$. Is this correct?

Comment: There are only four possibilities for the gcd: $1, 2, 13,$ and $26$.  It's pretty easy to eliminate 3 of those.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake copying the exercise. Already fixed it @DietrichBurde

Comment: Check edit @DietrichBurde

Comment: $\large x\mid x^2\Rightarrow\,(x,26) = \overbrace{(x,26,\color{#c00}{x^2}) = (x,26,\color{#c00}{10})}^{\textstyle \color{#c00}{x^2\equiv 10}\pmod{26}} = (x,(26,10)) = (x,2) = 2\ \ $